# apache server cant write to log files

Tags: linux, permissions, apache-http-server, python

I'm developing a Django app and I'm having a problem with logfiles.  I have a logger configured to write to `/var/log/django/django.log`.  When I try to start the server, I get a 500 error, and the error log says

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'djangologfile': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/django/django.log'
"httpd/error_log" 480L, 61112C
```

The permissions for both `django.log` and the `django` directory are 777.  Why can't the server write to the file?

Comment: The file permissions are `777`, but does the user which writes logs have access to that directory? (i.e., all the path should have `ugo+x` permissions for directories). Which OS are you using?

Comment: If the django directory has 777 permissions, shouldn't any user be able to write to that directory?  I didn't thing the user needed write permissions to the entire path.

Comment: The user that writes to the log needs to access each subdirectory one by one starting from `/`. So, `/var` should have execution permissions (`+x`) for everyone. Then `/var/log`. And then `/var/log/django`. If all of them have the `+x` bit for everyone, then I'd be interested in which OS are you using.

Comment: @nKn I made all directories in the path `777`.  Still no change

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @nKn Oracle Linux 7

Comment: Check if SELinux is not blocking that write access. Set `setenforce 0` and try again.

Comment: @nKn That worked.  Add this as an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `SELinux` is blocking that write attempt. You can either disable it running the following command:

```
setenforce 0
```

Or create a rule to allow it to write. To do so, check your system log file and copy the line that "denied", it should be like this:

```
audit(...): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=27984 comm="httpd" name="httpd" dev=sda6 ino=307469 scontext=root:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0 tclass=...
```

Copy it and run the following command:

```
audit2allow -M local << _EOF_
(paste the content)
_EOF_

semodule -i local.pp
```

That will create a permanent rule for it so you shouldn't need to disable SELinux.